# Allowing my users to push subscribers to their Aweber lists (security & tokens)

Tags: php, aweber

I'm creating a public app that pushes emails to my users' Aweber email lists.

I've gotten to the point where I can let my user authenticate their Aweber account and then push emails to that account. However, the authentication code provided by Aweber uses access tokens to verify my user's credentials.

I need my code to continuously be able to access their list, so I'm assuming I would now need to store these tokens on my server to the database in order to do so.

1) Is that how it usually works for apps like this?

2) What about security and things of that nature? Are access tokens usually encrypted then?

Answer (score 0):

AWeber must be using AuthorizationCodeGrant flow... probably. In that case, they are probably issuing a Refresh Token as well.

That Refresh Token allows you to get new tokens once they have expired. You should store both tokens and use them in order to make the API calls. Usually you must pass the token in the header of every single call. That's how Bearer Tokens work anyway. It's a standard.